# How to create search 'filter' using PHP & MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am working on a job portal Website. I have the following form code in my Webpage:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <h6>Location:</h6>
    <select class="form-control" onchange="if (this[this.selectedIndex].value !== '0') document.location.href=this.value;">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Anywhere</option>
        <option value="?l=Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
        <option value="?l=Noida">Noida</option>
    </select>
    <h6>Job Type:</h6>
    <select class="form-control" onchange="if (this[this.selectedIndex].value !== '0') document.location.href=this.value;">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="?t=Freelancer">Freelancer</option>
    </select>
</form>
<h6>Job Category:</h6>
    <select class="form-control" onchange="if (this[this.selectedIndex].value !== '0') document.location.href=this.value;">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="?c=data-scientist">Data Scientist</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

But everytime I click to get the selected option I get them seperately. Like this : [Getting seperated selection values from the form in the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3RDe.jpg)

I want to concat all these selected values in the URL based on whichever select box is selected first by user.

[I want to make search data appear as following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlGBp.png)

Please help! Click on the links to understand my question better. Sorry for my english! :(

Comment: Check your code. You are closing `form` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Slico/c333cgc6/) change it to fit your needs.

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    var url = "";
    $("select").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != 0) {
            url += $(this).val();
        }
    });
    $(".url").html(url);
});
```

It's a basic example you need to change the result to change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to change:

- Fix your `form` tag (it's being closed twice)
- Make the values *values* instead of URL segments
- Give your form elements names
- Instead of changing the document URL, simply submit the form

Something like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="get">
    <h6>Location:</h6>
    <select name="l" class="form-control" onchange="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Anywhere</option>
        <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
        <option value="Noida">Noida</option>
    </select>
    and so on...
```

Basically, it looks like you entirely over-engineered your form for what you want.  The functionality you're looking for is the default behavior of submitting a form.  So instead of trying to do clever things with the URLs, just submit the form.